# Java 8 forEach cannot get count in lambda expression

Tags: lambda, foreach

My code is:

```
    int count = 0;
    contactVisits.keySet().forEach(
            key -> {
                count++; //cannot reach count here 

                //.doing my stuff......

                // ..
            }
    );
```

i need count in lambda, counting with "count" variable but netbeans telling me a problem like 
*"local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final"*

Is there a way to get index count of map in Lambda expression 
or getting a variable outside ?

Comment: What do you mean by index count of a `Map` where there's no such thing called index in a map.

Comment: how can i call it? i like to fix my question.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is just use size() method on your map.

You may also use atomicinteger instead of int, and call getAndIncremend instead count++, however its not effective.

There is also stream().count() but i think first approach is the best.